# exception (handling) in c#

Tags: c#, exception, custom-exceptions

```
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     _errorCode = ErrorCodes.SqlGeneralError;
     CommonTools.vAddToLog(ex, _errorCode, _userID);
     throw new JOVALException(_errorCode);
 }
```

I use this peace of code to handle error to an custom exception called **`(JOVALException)`** but when an exception is occurred it is open "No source available" page and telled me that is no the **stack trace**  is empty 
How  could I solve this problem ?

**Edit**

```
 public JOVALException(ErrorCodes _errCode, String _message = "")
        {
            ErrMessage = _message;
            ErrCode = _errCode;

        }
```

here is my constructor, How can modify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to modify `JOVALException` class, by adding a constructor:

```
  public class JOVALException: Exception {
    ...
    // Note Exception "innerException" argument
    public JOVALException(ErrorCodes _errCode, Exception innerException, String _message = "")
      : base(_message, inner) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Another issue: try avoid code duplication

```
  ErrMessage = _message;
```

since `ErrMessage` is, in fact, a duplication of `Message` propepery; just call a *base class constructor*.

then

```
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     _errorCode = ErrorCodes.SqlGeneralError;
     CommonTools.vAddToLog(ex, _errorCode, _userID);
     throw new JOVALException(_errorCode, ex);  // <- Note "ex"
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Put `ex` into your `JOVALException` as an [inner exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/804f22sf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public JOVALException(ErrorCodes _errCode, String _message = "",
  Exception innerException = null) : base(_message, innerException)
{
  ErrMessage = _message;
  ErrCode = _errCode;
}
```

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh You need to add an appropriate constructor to `JOVALException` that calls the base constructor passing the inner exception. See link.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `throw new JOVALException(_errorCode);` you lose the stack trace of the original error.

Just do:

```
throw;
```

If you need to throw a `JOVALException` you'll need to modify your class slightly:

```
class JOVALException : Exception
{
    public JOVALException(string errorCode, Exception innerException)
        : base(errorCode, innerException)
    {

    }
}
```

And an example:

```
 try
 {
      int i = 0;
      int foo = i / i;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     _errorCode = ErrorCodes.SqlGeneralError;
     CommonTools.vAddToLog(ex, _errorCode, _userID);
     throw new JOVALException(_errorCode, ex);
 }
```

Comment: but I need to tell caller method that is "JOVALException" !